# Self Made Theme not showing up in Avaliable theme options

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I made a custom theme in my local wordpress. I added a style.css in the folder and an index.php. I also added a Images folder. But my theme is not showing up in avaliable themes! What can be the possible workaround? Help Please?

First 20 lines of style.css:

```
/*
Theme Name: test
Theme URI: http://company_name.com
Description: The test theme
Author: sankalp
Author URI: http://company_name.com
Version: 1.0

License:
License URI:

General comments (optional).
*/

    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; font-size: 100%; font: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; }
    article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
    body { line-height: 1;}
    ol, ul { list-style: none;}
    blockquote, q { quotes: none;}
    blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {content: ''; content: none;}
```

Comment: copy the twenty twelve theme and change the theme name from style.css..
check if that is working..

Answer (score 0):

I tried your style.css file as well and it is fine. Make sure you check over the simple things, eg, opening the correct development site

Answer (score 0):

For a theme to show up in WordPress you should upload the theme folder in `/wp-content/themes/`. Your theme folder should look like this:

```
/theme-folder/
    style.css
    index.php
```

Your style.css should include the following lines, as explained here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Theme_Stylesheet

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Ten
Theme URI: http://wordpress.org/
Description: The 2010 default theme for WordPress.
Author: wordpressdotorg
Author URI: http://wordpress.org/
Version: 1.0
Tags: black, blue, white, two-columns, fixed-width, custom-header, custom-background, threaded-comments, sticky-post, translation-ready, microformats, rtl-language-support, editor-style, custom-menu (optional)

License:
License URI:

General comments (optional).
*/
```

I usually only include the Theme Name, Theme URI, Author and Author URI and that seems to work just fine. :)

If you did all that make sure you're uploading your theme folder to the right webserver, possibly you're not uploading where you think you are uploading it?